# Is there any way to display container names in docker stats?

Tags: docker

I want to display state of all running container, so I could achieve it like the following:

> docker stats $(docker ps -q)

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O
04cdc87ba3cf        0.03%               468.8 MiB/3.784 GiB   12.10%              6.827 KiB/10.2 KiB
7d30fcbd8b36        0.09%               88.09 MiB/3.784 GiB   2.27%               28.23 KiB/289.2 KiB
a09ef63b2c59        97.94%              271.5 MiB/512 MiB     53.03%              3.644 MiB/190.2 KiB
a29681c1980f        0.10%               9.066 MiB/3.784 GiB   0.23%               2.538 KiB/648 B
```

but the column container is only showing the container id.  I need the container name though.  For example:

> docker stats lrlcms_web_1

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT      MEM %               NET I/O
lrlcms_web_1        0.09%               88.1 MiB/3.784 GiB   2.27%               28.85 KiB/289.2 KiB
```

So how do I get all the container names?  Just for:

> docker stats `all container's name'

For example:

> docker stats  lrlcms_db_1 lrlcms_redis_1

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O
lrlcms_db_1         0.05%               450.3 MiB/3.784 GiB   11.62%              8.737 KiB/10.2 KiB
lrlcms_redis_1      0.08%               7.383 MiB/3.784 GiB   0.19%               4.448 KiB/648 B
```

Comment: `docker stats` is not able to display more than this at the moment (by the way it would be handy to sort on any column) , the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#stats says also `Note: If you want more detailed information about a container's resource usage, use the API endpoint.`

Comment: Maybe if instead of passing the ids, you pass a list of container names, something in the idea of `docker stats $(docker ps | awk ' NR > 1 {print $2}'` (untested, but you get the idea, I do not have access at a docker prompt at the moment)

Comment: try `docker stats $(docker ps | awk '{if(NR>1) print $2}')`

Comment: should be default with Docker 17.10 version: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20973

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Or, using plain "docker ps" instead of "awk"... note "--format" is normally used with "docker inspect":

```
docker stats $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}')
```

---

2017-02-12 See manat's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42060599/72717). Docker 1.13.0 "stats" can display the container name in "--format":

```
docker stats --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"
```

Comment: Best possible answer. Teacher two things at a time :-)

Comment: You can also sort the statistics. And also get rid of some container name prefix-suffix, e.g:
`docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}" |sed -E 's/^local.cluster.([a-z1-2\-]+).1(.*)/\1\2/'|sed -E 's/NAME {17}/NAME /'| sort -k 2 -h -r`
(assuming container names have default prefix "local-cluster-" and default suffix "-1)
Sample sorts by CPU% ascending.

Answer (score 52):

```
docker stats $(docker ps | awk '{if(NR>1) print $NF}')
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks so much, could you please provide an explanation?

Answer (score 12):

Since docker 1.13.0 [(#27797)](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/27797), there's a format option which support container name. So you can run it like this:

```
docker stats --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"
```

See Docker [Formatting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/#formatting) for full details.

Comment: Please fix dead link

Answer (score 4):

A bit hacky, but works:

`docker stats $(docker ps | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $NF}')`

`tail -n +2` is there to remove `docker ps` header line, and finally `awk '{print $NF}'` prints the last column (i.e. container name) for every input line

Comment: This worked for me better than the actual answer, but in my case I was removing all the containers (I had A LOT of them). so my command was `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $NF}')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get the stats with container name, cpu and memory usage in table format

docker stats --all --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"

For Json format

docker stats --all --format "json {{.Name}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).