# Check Resources Used by each Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

How do you check the amount of resources (CPU, memory etc) being used by each Docker container that is running on the (Ubuntu) server?

Answer (score 7):

you have `docker stats` see the doc

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stats/

for example you can do

`docker stats $(docker ps -q)`

(that will display the id of the containers or if you want the name, see

[Is there any way to display container names in docker stats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732313/is-anyway-to-get-all-containers-name/30733337#30733337)

, you can also you `docker top` if you are interested in a specific container

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/top/

Answer (score 2):

this displays real-time resource usage across all running containers on a single docker engine or entire swarm cluster

```
docker stats $( docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}' )
```

sample output

```
CONTAINER              CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O           PIDS
dockercoins_webui_1    0.66%               19.23 MB / 16.72 GB   0.12%               309.8 kB / 605.8 kB   61.44 kB / 0 B      9
dockercoins_worker_1   4.01%               13.18 MB / 16.72 GB   0.08%               834.5 kB / 920.5 kB   98.3 kB / 0 B       1
dockercoins_rng_1      0.70%               19.03 MB / 16.72 GB   0.11%               412.8 kB / 441.7 kB   2.388 MB / 0 B      1
dockercoins_hasher_1   0.59%               19.67 MB / 16.72 GB   0.12%               477.6 kB / 372.7 kB   1.438 MB / 0 B      22
dockercoins_redis_1    0.18%               6.877 MB / 16.72 GB   0.04%               178.8 kB / 80.11 kB   5.771 MB / 0 B      3
web                    0.02%               11.06 MB / 16.72 GB   0.07%               87.19 kB / 648 B      0 B / 0 B           1
db                     0.01%               14.11 MB / 16.72 GB   0.08%               87.84 kB / 648 B      0 B / 9.851 MB      7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use [`docker-scout`](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/03/16/monitoring-docker) (not free though) or [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) (Apache license).

It seems better than:

- install the agent and its dependencies directly on the host (it's better as a container)
- Running an agent in every container is bad (lots of overhead)

> cAdvisor (Container Advisor) provides container users an understanding of the resource usage and performance characteristics of their running containers.
>   It is a running daemon that collects, aggregates, processes, and exports information about running containers.
>   Specifically, for each container it keeps resource isolation parameters, historical resource usage, histograms of complete historical resource usage and network statistics

```
sudo docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:latest
```

Comment: You have many solutions, including your docker-scout on this link  https://blog.docker.com/2015/06/etp-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Google cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) - cAdvisor monitors resource usage and performance characteristics for Docker containers. Its free and provides all the resource usage statistics for each container that you need.

If you want to store the cAdvisor performance statistics for visualization, analytics and capacity planning, you can use [ATSD](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/docker-cadvisor/). You can visualize the statistics for each container or each host, there are also consolidated portals for multiple hosts and portals for custom sets of containers sorted by role/type.